# Facebook thumbnail URL checked fine by Linter, but no image shows up

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've installed the Easy Facebook Share Thumbnail Plugin for Wordpress to take care of the opengraph meta for my site.
Site is hawknpoke.com

When I check my posts via FB linter, everyting semms to be correct. Except for the image thumbnail: it is blank. The url is correct though: if I click the 'blank' thumbnail, it took me to the correct image.
When I post the url to FB, the thumbnail is missing.

Please help.

Thanks,
Fredy

Comment: Okay! So I've found the problem. Our admin set a hotlinking image restriction via cPanel. Now that he has adjusted the settings, FB thumbnails are working perfectly.

Comment: I'm using tumblr and it was fine before, i don't think they added a hotlink protection.